# Custom taxonomy auto suggest not working in wordpress admin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, autocomplete

I've added to my theme a new custom taxonomy in order to add future filtering capabilities to a custom post type called 'product' (I use the wooCommerce plugin which defines this custom post type).

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Types de produit', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Type de produit', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Type de produit', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'Tous les types', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Type parent', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Type parent :', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nouveau type', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Ajouter nouveau type', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Modifier type', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Mettre à jour type', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Séparer les types avec des virgules', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Rechercher types', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Ajouter ou supprimer types', 'my-child-theme' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choisir parmi les types les plus utilisés', 'my-child-theme' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);

register_taxonomy( 'product_item_type', 'product', $args ); // Add this tax to the post_type 'product' from WooCommerce
```

Everything is fine with this new taxonomy execpt I can't link easily a product_item_type to a product in the product edit screen.

If I begin to write the name of the tag, nothing is suggested.

If I click on the "Choose from most used ..." link, an error tells me that "No tag was found".

If I enter a tag, then add it, the tag is created, but if I enter the name of an existing tag, this new tag is added with a new slug.

I've no error in my JS Console and WPDebug doesn't tell anything :(

So, did I forgot something when I created the custom taxonomy or is there something particular to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: So does this Taxonomy have a bunch of terms already? It cannot suggest terms if none exist.

Comment: So you think I'm stupid? :) Yes it does! But existing terms are never suggested on the edit input... It works great with standard tags!

Comment: Edit input on what screen? The post editor screen or the taxonomy management screen?

Comment: ...as it is said in my question "in the product edit screen"

Comment: So are you saying, you want the term input to suggest a new term name based on existing terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing anything, everything seems OK today. The auto-suggest works and suggests me existing tags when I begin to type a word... I don't know why but maybe there was a problem because I've firstly created this custom taxonomy as hierachical before I decided to change it to non-hierarchical.